# Logs not being collected by Azure Log Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

I am working with Azure Log Analytics to push syslogs from Linux Vm to Azure. I created a new Log Analytics workspace, connected a RHEL 6.10 VM with it and then configured the data sources to Syslog and some common performance counters. But I don't see any data being collected from my VM to ALA.

The only problem which I suspect is configuration of the NSG rules on the subnet of which this VM is part of. I created the NSG with outbound rules as following.

1. Created a rule named “DenyInternet” which denies all internet access with following parameters

```
Source - *
Destination - Service Tag\
Service tag - Internet
Destination port range - *
Protocol - “any”
Action - Deny
Priority - 4000
```

2. Created another outbound rule which allows connectivity to Azure Storage with following parameters

```
Source - *
Destination - Service Tag
Destination service tag - “Storage”
Destination port range - *
Protocol - “any”
Action - allow
Priority - 100
```

3. Create third outbound rule which allows connectivity to Azure Log Analytics with following parameters

```
Source - *
Destination - Service Tag
Destination service tag - AzureMonitor
Destination port range - *
Protocol - “any”
Action - allow
Priority - 110
```

So as per the above rules applied on the NSG it should Deny all Internet access but should allow access to Storage and Azure Log Analytics, but still I believe logs are not being pushed to ALA workspace.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by making a small change in my `DenyInternet` rule. I changed the `source` from `any` to `VirtualNetwork` and that resolved the issue.

To explain more on it, I basically want to restrict the traffic that is being generated from the VirtualNetwork and not any source which blocks the traffic generated by the agent as well.